# Python 'call_command' mock is used in other tests as well

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Using Django 1.10 and python 3.5.1.

I'm trying to mock 'call_command' function to throw an exception. The problem is that seems like the moment it gets the 'side_effect' function - it keeps to it also for other tests. What am I doing wrong or how can I 'revert' the side_effect from that function?

In this example, after running one of the tests, all other tests that run afterwards will throw the same exception even if it's not supposed to throw exception in that test.

```
 def test_run_migrations_raise_exception(self):

    with mock.patch('django.core.management.call_command', return_value=None, side_effect=Exception('e message')):
        self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)
        call_command('run_data_migrations')
        self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)

 def test_run_migrations_raise_flow_exception(self):

    with mock.patch('django.core.management.call_command', return_value=None, side_effect=FlowException(500, 'fe message', {'a': 1})):
        self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)
        call_command('run_data_migrations')
        self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)
```

Comment: Are you sure, your mock even takes effect? Could it be that the Exception is an actual exception which is thrown (and not the one specified by you in the side_effect?)

Comment: Can you show the code for `check_migrations_called`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not patch a function that is in your module-local (i.e. Python's "global" - which is actually "module") namespace.

When in Python you do

```
from module.that import this
```

`this` becomes a variable on the module that contains the import statement. Any changes to "module.that.this" will affect the object pointed in the other module, but using only `this` will still reefer to the original object.

Perhaps your code is not exactly as you show us, or maybe "mock.pacth" can find out that the module-local `call_command` is pointing to `django.core.management.call_command` in the other module when it makes the patch - but not when reversing the patch. The fact is your module-local name `call_command` is being changed.

You can fix that by simply changing your code to not bind a module variable directly to the function you want to change:

from django.core import management
 def test_run_migrations_raise_exception(self):

```
with mock.patch('django.core.management.call_command', return_value=None, side_effect=Exception('e message')):
    self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)
    management.call_command('run_data_migrations')
    self.check_migrations_called(MigrationTracker.objects.all(), data_migrations_settings_in_db)
```

I hope you can understand that and solve this problem. Now, that said, this use of `mock` makes no sense at all: the idea of using mock is that some callable used indirectly by code you call within the code-block that applies the patch does not have the original effect - so the intermetiate code can run and be tested. You are calling directly the mock object - so it will have none of the original code -  calling `call_command('run_data_migrations')` runs no code on your code base at all, and thus, there is nothing there to test. It just calls the mocked instance, and it will not change the status of anything that could be detected with `check_migrations_called`.

Comment: Indeed that's not all the code, but the separation of the import (import management) did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @user2880391 comment is on point, the separation of the import solved the problem for me.